# UIEdgeInsetMake unset when changing between Tab View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a Tab View Controller which manages two ViewControllers. One of the ViewControllers is a GMSMapView. I'm preventing overlap with the navigation by doing the following:

```
self.mapView_.padding =
UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.topLayoutGuide.length + 5,0,self.bottomLayoutGuide.length + 5,0);
```

This works great on the initial load. But when I toggle to the other tab and then come back, the position button drops below the tab bar at the bottom. It seems that the padding property is ignored on the second appearance.

Initially I set the padding property in the `viewWillAppear` method, but I've also tested in `viewDidLoad` and the issue was the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it's the padding that's being reset, and not that the map view size is changing?

Comment: @SaxonDruce No I'm not sure. What's an easy way to test that?

Comment: Maybe in `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`, ie when a tab has been switched (you'll need to implement `UITabBarControllerDelegate`), you can log the current size of the map view and the padding, and see if that helps work out what's going wrong.

Comment: @SaxonDruce Something like `NSLog(self.view.size...)`?